# Undirected graph generation with given connectivity

Tags: algorithm, graph, connectivity

I want to find an algorithm to generate an undirected graph with a given size and a given connectivity, where each vertex has exactly the specified number of edges coming from it. The closest thing I've found so far is this:

[Random simple connected graph generation with given sparseness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041517/random-simple-connected-graph-generation-with-given-sparseness)

The difference here being that I'm less interested in the total number of edges in the graph (though that can easily be computed too) -- what I'm looking for is a guarantee that each vertex has exactly the given number of connections.

For example:

```
Input: Size - 6   Connectivity - 4
Output: Undirected graph with 6 verteces and (6*4/2)=12 edges, where each vertex has 4 connnections.
```

I am assuming that my inputs will have a valid output.

Comment: This might help, and may in fact be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761401/how-to-create-a-symmetric-matrix-of-1s-and-0s-with-constant-row-and-column-sum

Comment: I didn't know that a graph where all nodes have the same number of neighbors was called a "regular graph." That gives me a lot of new places to research. Thanks for your help! I'll come back and post a definitive answer if I can come up with one.

Comment: The accepted answer in the question I linked contains an algorithm to generate random graphs of this type. The only thing you really need to play around with is how many times to swap edges.